# Today Extension background update

Tags: objective-c, today-extension, ios8-today-widget, ios10-today-widget, ios9-today-widget

Can I update data in Today Extension, while it's in background? In a sense not visibile on screen. Or Only it's showing on the screen in method widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler??? thx for answers!

Answer (score 1):

**Today extension** is automatically updated in the background. The `NCWidgetProviding` protocol method `widgetPerformUpdate` handles this.

```
   func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: @escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Swift.Void)
    {
        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
    }
```

**This method is called:**

1. When widget is updated in background.
2. Before widget snapshot is taken.

For more you can refer to: https://github.com/pgpt10/Today-Widget